# ng-link is not working with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to change content using radio buttons. content changes when click on radio button but radio is not checked it stays empty, i know something is wrong, can someone suggest me a solution.

```
             <div class="radio-custom radio-default radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" ng-link="['OneWayFlight']" id="oneWayFlight" name="FlightType" />
                <label for="oneWayFlight">One way</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-custom radio-default radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" ng-link="['ReturnTripFlight']" id="roundTripFlight" name="FlightType"/>
                <label for="roundTripFlight">Round Trip</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-model instead of ng-link.

```
<div class="radio-custom radio-default radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="flightType" value="Round Trip">Round trip<br/>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="flightType" value="One Way">One Way<br/>   
   <tt>Flight Type = {{flightType | json}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```